# Python Board Game Trouble

Tags: python, python-3.x

this is for a school class i am learning computer scicence and i am working on a this code and i have been having some trouble and it is very hard to understand my teacher so i was wondering if anyone would be willing to help me with this program

```
gridl=[]
inputO=input("Please Enter").split(",") #Input Statement 1
numberO=inputO[0]#The Number Of "O" in the Input
Ocord=inputO[1:len(inputO)]#The O's
numberO=int(numberO)
for j in range(0,len(Ocord)):
    gridl.append(Ocord[j-1:j+1])
for i in range(0:len(gridl))
    newgrid=[]
inputX=input("Please Enter").split(",") #Input Statement 2
numberX=inputX[0] #The Number Of "X" in the Input
Xcord=inputX[1:len(inputX)]
print (Xcord)
```

The Rules and instructions:

[image]

Test inputs and outputs:

[image]

Comment: 3rd line, input0[0] won't give you the number of 0s, but the 1st element of the splitting, in your case everything until the first `,`

Comment: I suspect the problem is not the teacher ..

Comment: The problem is, this is for an assignment, and you have done basically no work. "Please do my homework" is a common question, but not one we really like to see.

Comment: Kindly do not deface your post.

Answer (score 2):

This is for an assignment, and you have done nothing except try (and fail) to get the first couple of lines read in. So I'm not going to be able to help you with your code - there's no code.

Instead, here are some hints:

1. Don't do things piecemeal if you can avoid it. When you're reading input, read all the input. When you're parsing the input, parse all the input.
2. You're going to make a bunch of mistakes doing this. It would help you to be able to "see" what you're doing. So, even though it's not required, I **strongly** suggest you make a function that will print out your game board. That way, you'll be able to "see" the situations of the pieces.
3. You're going to be doing some common operations, like adding pieces and getting the value of pieces. Make functions for those actions, if you can. Raise exceptions when things go wrong. The more time you spend being strict at the bottom levels, the less stupid mistakes you allow yourself to make at the top levels.
4. Get your types right. According to the instructions, everything in the input and output will be a number, except for the word 'None'. So you need to make sure that your input is all converted to numbers as soon as possible.